# Jenkins - How to replace multiple labels with some other text

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is a great tool for automating some of the routine tasks that gets landed on IT support staff.
But the problem is, Jenkins is so focused on build automation, and for a non IT person, it can be confusing to use it for non build work.

I want to replace the phrases containing "build" with other things

Build Now     => Run Job Now (there is a plugin to replace this) 
Build History => Job Run History  
Build Queue   => Job Queue  
Build Executor Status => Job Executor Status  
Last Build => Last Run  
Last Stable Build => Last Stable Run  
...

I hope you got the picture. How can I do this ?

Please help.

Thanks, 
Harshana

Answer (score 0):

In general, jenkins uses all labels from `Messages.properties` file https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/model/Messages.properties. So it should be possible to made a custom one and pass it to jenkins. Should be in the same direction as adding a new translation.

Comment: Thanks @kofemann looks like I'll have to write a plugin for this.